# PHP Laravel view table design

Tags: php, foreach, laravel

I've been working on a project where I have 3 tables of dates, times and usernames and when I join them the last view is:

```
same date - same time - diff username
same date - same time - diff username
diff date - diff time - diff username
```

An example with real data would be:

```
2014-01-03 | 10.08 | alexrussell
2014-01-05 | 11.15 | geartz
2014-01-05 | 14.23 | geartz
2014-02-02 | 13.44 | alexrussell
2014-02-02 | 13.44 | geartz
2014-02-02 | 18.21 | alexrussell
```

What I'm trying is to create a table where the data that's the same from row to row is grouped:

```
 -----------------------------------
| Date       | Time  | Username     |
|------------|-------|--------------|
| 2014-01-03 | 10.08 | alexrussell  |
|------------|-------|--------------|
|            | 11.15 | geartz       |
| 2014-01-15 |-------|--------------|
|            | 14.23 | geartz       |
|------------|-------|--------------|
|            |       | alexrussell  |
|            | 13.44 |--------------|
| 2014-02-02 |       | geartz       |
|            |-------|--------------|
|            | 18.21 | alexrussell  |
 -----------------------------------
```

I have 1 object and I'm using foreach to parse it. I tried several selects with distinct but that way, I can't include other objects in table so code gives error like 1 select with distinct for date and 1 for the rest which have "where" statement. I tried 1 object with several arrays in it but again since I'm using foreach, I can only fill 1 column and next column requires other object.

I also tried giving a rowspan per object count but It didn't work since I can't exactly get the user count.

There must be a way and I'm totally stuck on this. Probably I'm not the first one encountering a problem like this.

Comment: I think the answer to this question is going to be complex. However, if you set up your relationships correctly you may be able to do the grouping with multiple SQL queries. To create this kind of table from one SQL query (with, presumably, redundant data) you'll end up doing a lot of looping logic in PHP. It's doable, of course, but you may find that as long as the perf hit isn't too bad, just doing multiple queries would be better code.

Comment: Also, just to help answerers out, are the dates and times always the same and you just want a 'rowspan' effect in the username column? Or could you also be wanting to do the same with time too?

Comment: The date has many times and 1 time has many users. I'm just trying to categorize everything under same dates.

Comment: Okay but if the date has many times and times many users it seems to me like you'd need two levels of 'rowspanning': http://laravel.io/bin/lnka

Comment: Exactly like this ^
I tried 
http://pastebin.com/Gix0njd7
but couldnt do it

Comment: Cool, I've suggested an update to your post with the example so answerers know what's going on. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Cool - I don't really have time to answer this myself I'm afraid but I hope I've helped. FYI though I don't think you'll be able to set rowspan stuff on the fly (as the rowspan needs to be done before you know how many things there are), so you'll need to prepare your data first. So in your controller, you'd go through the array here and count how many username there are per time and therefore how many usernames per date and hold this in some structured manner in order to get the rowspan values.